# mongodb go: `mongo: no documents in result`

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go, mongo-go-driver

I have a pretty simple entry in my mongoDB database:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"609b15511a048e03dda05861"},"password":"test_password","answer":"test_answer"}
```

And when I use filter parameters in the Atlas UI, I am able to pull up results.

Filter:

```
{"password": "test_password"}
```

However, when I call to the DB, I keep getting the error `mongo: no documents in result`

```golang
filter := bson.M{"password": "test_password"}
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
err := collection.FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&result)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("%v", err)
}
```

I appear to be connecting properly to the collection. Any thoughts?

Comment: The code you posted should work, the problem is somewhere else (unknown to us). Test if you can get other (all) documents with an empty filter.

Comment: What is the definition of `result`? Also, try the find with `ctx.TODO()`. In general, it is a better idea to use `bson.D` for defining the query _filter_ (bson.M cannot guarantee the order of entries - relevant with multiple filter conditions).

Comment: `result` is defined as `type Result struct {
 Password string `json:"password"`
 Answer   string `json:"answer`
}`. And I'll try that `ctx.TODO()`

Comment: I can't seem to get anything with an empty filter. Perhaps I'm not connected after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't connecting properly to the db after all.

I was connecting to my collection like so:

```
collection := client.Database("DB_NAME").Collection("COLLECTION_NAME")
```

And since it didn't throw an error, I incorrectly assumed this was right. You can look at your collections and databases with the following:

```golang
databases, _ := client.ListDatabaseNames(ctx, bson.M{})
log.Printf("%v", databases)
collections, _ := client.Database("DATABASES").ListCollectionNames(ctx, bson.M{})
log.Printf("%v", collections)
```